# Display a string variable in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently doing a simili-HangMan project. As I looked through many other projects up here, I haven't found what I was looking for exactly.

Notes:
* The variable motRechercher is the randomized word.
* It can be used everywhere - I did a get set for it.

**MY QUESTION IS:** I want to display a string in a textbox that is a random word selected from a list, how do I do that?

Here's my code for the textbox:

```
private void txtMot_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= motRechercher.Length; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(motRechercher);
        sb[i] = '_';
        string sba = sb.ToString();
        txtMot.Text=sba;
    } 
}
```

If the word is for an example : Cat. It should display: _ _ _

Here's my code for the random word selector (It works) - It's mostly to give an idea:

```
private void btnDemarrer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Random rdn = new Random();
    int nbreAleatoire = rdn.Next(0, 27);
    motRechercher = lesMots[nbreAleatoire];
}
```

If you have any questions regarding my code I'll edit it to make it easier for you to understand/help me.

Comment: Don't create the StringBuilder in the loop. Don't create a new Random instance in _Click event.

Comment: Okay, sure. How do I fix it Mr. L.B then? Give ideas to help me concretise the project.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user3078728 How about to think about comments before asking for working code.

Comment: I am new to C# winform, and looking forward to learn, to do that I kind of need some commands and to understand what to do after removing the Random instance or the StringBuilder... Could you help me by providing an exemple or two with small explanations?

Comment: what is this motRechercher ? is this a string/int/list...or what ?

Comment: @user1849541 - It is a string, a word randomly picked from a list of 28 words as said in the post.

Comment: then have you tested with @kumarch1 answer. it should work

Comment: Yes I did, it actually didn't work, but I think it's because of the line sb[i] = '_'; as I said in his awnser comment zone. It caused the program to crash.

Comment: hi please see the modified one's

Comment: NEW MODIFIED ONE WORKS LIKE A CHARM - Thank you Mr. kumarch1 for your time here. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
private void txtMot_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= motRechercher.Length; i++)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(motRechercher);
       sb[i] = '_';
       string sba = sb.ToString();
       txtMot.Text=sba;
   } 

}
```

add another button for next random no to populate to text box.

inside button click do this which will check the length and get the data for you:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(motRechercher.Length > 0)
   {
     String str = new String('_', motRechercher.Length);
     txtMot.Text = str;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tested this awnser - it caused my program to crash. Although, I think it's due to the lane (sb[i] = '_';). I placed it in comment and it stopped crashing... How do you guys think I can fix that? The point of the line is to change the letters from the word (motRechercher <-- string variable) to " _ "... Ty for the awnser tho!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this might be what you're after:

```
bool changing = false; // variable in class-scope

private void txtMot_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (changing == false)
    {
        try
        {
            changing = true;
            String str = new String('_', motRechercher.Length);
            txtMot.Text = str;
        }
        finally
        {
            changing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your thing should work, but it doesn't seem to take effect. What I mean here : txtMot.Text = str; doesn't show up in the textbox called txtMot.

Thanks for the post it still removed multiple lines of code!